# "less of" and "lesser" with uncountable nouns

Tags: uncountable-nouns

> **1.** *She spends **less of her time** playing tennis now*. - correct example
>
> **2.** *She had **less of reason** to complain than I.* - incorrect example (I know we can make "*reason*" countable and write "*less of a reason*")

In both **1.** and **2.** we have the uncountable nouns "*time*" and "*reason*" after "*less of*". Why, then, is **1.** correct but **2.** incorrect?

---

> **3.** *people of **lesser importance***. - correct example
>
> **4.** *She had **lesser reason** to complain than I.* - incorrect example (I know we can make "*reason*" countable and write "*a lesser reason*")

In both **3.** and **4.** we have the uncountable nouns "*importance*" and "*reason*" after "*lesser*". Why, then, is **3.** correct but **4.** incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: In 1/2, _less_ is pronominal in function; the meaning is ‘a smaller amount/portion (of)’, so it makes some sense that it would work with something like _time_, which can be semantically subdivided into smaller units, but not with _reason_, which can’t (what would a smaller amount of reason be?). Why 4 doesn’t work is a better question. “She had _better_ reason to complain than I” seems slightly better, but not felicitous either. My immediate guess would be that _than_ constructions prefer quantifiers to adjectives where semantically and grammatically possible.

Comment: _Less reason to complain_ seems OK to me (but not _less of reason_).

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet, As far as I'm concerned, "_less of_" can also mean a degree: "_It is less of a problem than I'd expected_." Therefore **2.** could have had this meaning.